# GUITHREADINFO::flags are always zero

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi

I'm trying to detect if there is a menu opened for the main window,
something like:

```
GUITHREADINFO gtinf = { sizeof(GUITHREADINFO) };

GetGUIThreadInfo(0, &gtinf);
if (gtinf.flags & GUI_INMENUMODE || gtinf.flags & GUI_POPUPMENUMODE)
{
    //...
}
```

but **gtinf.flags** is always zero, even if menu is obviously opened.
Only **hwndActive** and **hwndFocus** are correctly set.
What's the problem ?

Comment: If you are looking for information of a particular thread, don't just pass `0` as the *idThread* argument. Assuming that you want to retrieve the information for the calling thread, pass the return value of [GetCurrentThreadId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183.aspx) instead.

Comment: @IInspectable there is nothing in the documentation to indictate that a specific thread ID must be used to get the flags populated. Passing 0 simply retrieves info about the foreground thread, so flags should still be populated if there are any flags to return.

Comment: @olpchk did you make sure the function is actually returning nonzero? Is the foreground app using a *standard* menu?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Of course it's possible to query GUI thread info about the foreground thread by passing `0` for the *idThread* parameter. The OP, however, is asking about *"the main window"*, i.e. a specific thread (that may or may not be the foreground thread). Passing `0` here is a bug.

Comment: It turned out that app uses non-standard mechanism for displaying menus, and therefore gui thread is not aware of.
Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that app uses non-standard mechanism for displaying menus, and therefore gui thread is not aware of. – olpchk